# Ambigous constructor call with list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

```
struct A {
    A(int) {}
};

struct B {
    B(A) {}
};

int main() {
    B b({0});
}
```

The construction of `b` gives the following errors:

```
In function 'int main()':
24:9: error: call of overloaded 'B(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous
24:9: note: candidates are:
11:2: note: B::B(A)
10:8: note: constexpr B::B(const B&)
10:8: note: constexpr B::B(B&&)
```

I was expecting `B::B(A)` to be called, why is it ambiguous in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a class, `A` with a user-defined constructor:

```
struct A
{
    A(int) {}
};
```

and another one, `B`, accepting `A` as a constructor parameter:

```
struct B
{
    B(A) {}
};
```

then in order to perform the initialization as below:

```
B b({0});
```

the compiler has to consider the following candidates:

```
B(A);         // #1
B(const B&);  // #2
B(B&&);       // #3
```

trying to find an implicit conversion sequence from `{0}` to each of the parameters.

Note that `B b({0})` does not list-initialize `b` -- the (copy-)list-initialization applies to a constructor parameter itself.

Since the argument is an initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence needed to match the argument to a parameter is defined in terms of list-initialization sequence [[over.ics.list]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list):

> When an argument is an initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), it is not an expression and special rules apply for converting it to a parameter type.

It reads:

> [...], if the parameter is a non-aggregate class X and overload resolution per 13.3.1.7 chooses a single
>   best constructor of X to perform the initialization of an object of type X from the argument initializer list,
>   the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence with the second standard conversion
>   sequence an identity conversion. If multiple constructors are viable but none is better than the others, the
>   implicit conversion sequence is the ambiguous conversion sequence. User-defined conversions are allowed
>   for conversion of the initializer list elements to the constructor parameter types except as noted in 13.3.3.1.

For #1 to be viable, the following call must be valid:

```
A a = {0};
```

which is correct due to [[over.match.list]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list#1.2):

> — If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

i.e., class `A` has a constructor that accepts an `int` argument.

For #2 to be a valid candidate, the following call must be valid:

```
const B& b = {0};
```

which according to [[over.ics.ref]/p2](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#2):

> When a parameter of reference type is not bound directly to an argument expression, the conversion sequence is the one required to convert the argument expression to the referenced type according to [over.best.ics]. Conceptually, this conversion sequence corresponds to copy-initializing a temporary of the referenced type with the argument expression. Any difference in top-level cv-qualification is subsumed by the initialization itself and does not constitute a conversion.

translates to:

```
B b = {0};
```

Once again, following [[over.ics.list]/p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#6.2):

> User-defined conversions are allowed for conversion of the initializer list elements to the constructor parameter types [...]

the compiler is allowed to use the user-defined conversion:

```
A(int);
```

to convert the argument `0` to `B`'s constructor parameter `A`.

For candidate #3, the same reasoning applies as in #2. Eventually, the compiler cannot choose between the aforementioned implicit conversion sequences <sup>{citation needed}</sup>, and reports ambiguity.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but probably it goes like this

Comment: seems better explained to me.

Answer (score 3):

`B b({0})` can result in a call to either of the following:

1. `B::B(A)`
2. Copy constructor of `B`: constructing a temporary `B`object from `{0}` and
   then copying it over to `b`.

Hence the ambiguity.

It can be resolved if you call `B b{0}`, which directly uses the defined constructor with no copy constructor involvement.

**EDIT:**

Regarding how point 2 is valid:

`B` has a constructor which accepts `A`. Now, `A` can be constructed by an `int`. Also, `int` can be constructed via the initialization list. That's why this is a valid case. Had `A`'s constructor been `explicit`, automatic casting from `{0}` to `int` would have failed, resulting in no ambiguity.

Comment: This is what the compiler says, and it does not explain why it happens

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Not sure what you mean by *"why it happens"*. Ambiguity occurs when the overload resolution finds more than one possibility, which is clearly the case here.

Comment: Oh, so *ambiguity* results from an *ambiguous* call? I would never guess

Comment: *"Ambiguity occurs when the overload resolution finds more than one possibility"*, the compiler already said which call is ambiguous, and listed candidates, the question is why the call is ambiguous under the current rules and whether it should be ambiguous

Comment: @CinCout in most cases, when overload resolution finds more than one possibility, there is a single preferred possibility that wins the ranking process

Comment: I don't follow option 2. Why does `B` get constructed from an initializer list with a 0? I could easily be missing something but at the very least this is not obvious and deserves explanation. `B` does not have any constructors taking an integer, or an initialization list, and it doesn't even have a default constructor!

Comment: Added explanation.

Comment: "*Had A's constructor been explicit, automatic casting from {0} to int would have failed, resulting in no ambiguity.*", did you try it ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: It is no longer ambiguous, there are no valid candidates ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The code compiles fine with [GCC8](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HNRMJnjQ7eFGaAgB).

This shouldn't be ambiguous calling. For the copy/move constructor of `B` being invoked, then for `B b({0});` the following steps are required:

1. construct `A` from `0` by `A::A(int)`
2. construct `B` from `A` constructed in step1 by `B::B(A)`
3. construct `b` from `B` constructed in step2 by copy/move constructor of `B`.

That means two user-defined conversions (step#1 and #2) are required, but this is not allowed in one implicit convertion sequence.

Comment: @ashen What compiler (and version) are you using?

Comment: That is the correct answer. It fails on icc and vc++ v141 (2017) compilers.

Comment: What happened to GCC 7? Did it get eaten by the same thing that ate Microsoft's Windows 9?

Comment: @CodyGray branched off from trunk (8.0)

Comment: @songyuanyao gcc 4.9.2. I've tried your link, it only compiles with gcc 8 under c++1z. If you try earlier versions, it still does not compile...

Comment: @ashen I noticed that too. I tried to find out if something changes from C++17 but failed. The code should work fine from C++11, as far as I can see.

Comment: [\[over.match.funcs\]/p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#6) implies that a total of two user-defined conversions are allowed in a list-initialization sequence

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I think there should be some explicit statements about that. But I can't find any in [dcl.init.list](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list)..

Comment: @songyuanyao unless it's an initialization list within another initialization list, a user-defined conversion is allowed for the elements; check the examples from [\[over.ics.list\]/p6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#6), `h({"foo"});` in particular